# Error in Multiplication of matrix

Tags: c++, windows, matrix

Error in Multiplication of matrixError in Multiplication of matrixError in Multiplication of matrix

```
Matrix operator * (Matrix tmp)
{
    Matrix prod;
    prod.size = size;
    prod.ptr = new int *[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)

        prod.ptr[i] = new int [size];

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
                {
                     *(*(prod.ptr+i)+j) += *(*(ptr+i)+k) * *(*(tmp.ptr+k)+j);
                }
            }
        }           
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Before you proceed with the multiplication, don't forget to initialize the elements of you `prod` matrix to 0, because they will then accumulate sums.

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
>     prod.ptr[i] = new int [size];
> ```

After this, initialize the elements of the result matrix to 0:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        prod.ptr[i][j] = 0;
```

p.s: your code works only for square matrices (#rows = #columns)